# How to await for a function or a database query? And then process results and finally send them back

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have this scenario:

```
app.get('/', async function (request, response) 
{
     await foo(DbConnection).then((result) => console.log("response ready"));
})

let foo = async function (DbConnection)
{
    const myQuery = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

    DbConnection.query(myQuery, async function(err, results) {
       console.log("query ready");
       await bar(results).then((response) => console.log("bar done"))
    })
    return; // go back to app.get() to send stuff to client
}

let bar = async function (results)
{   
    console.log("inside bar");
    await ThirdPartyAPI(result).then((value)) => return value);
}
```

Briefly:

- I receive GET request from client
- I call foo() which query data base and apply functions on results
- I process results using third party API which takes time to finish
- I send final results back to client

I am expecting to see:

> query ready -> inside bar -> bar done -> response ready

But I instead see:

> response ready -> query ready -> inside bar -> bar done

Client is receiving `undefined` since nothing was ready when `response.send()`

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you're mixing `async/await` syntax and callbacks. Use `async` function only when you want to do something with the result of async call inside this function.

Also that, specific to your case, you need to *promisify* `connection.query()` - create a promise. See below the correct pattern with a working code:

```
app.get('/', async (request, response) => {
    // waiting for the result of foo
    let result = await foo();
    console.log("response ready");
});

let foo = async () => {
    const myQuery = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

    // getting the result of the query
    let results = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => connection.query(myQuery, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(results);
      }
    }));
    console.log("query ready");
    // call bar and waiting the result
    let res = await bar(results);
    console.log("bar done");
    // return resolved promise
    return res;
}

let bar = (results) => {   
    console.log("inside bar");
    // just return a promise, we don't need the result here
    return ThirdPartyAPI(result);
}
```

**Explanation about using `async/await`**. The power of `async/await` is that it lets you write asynchronous code using synchronous language constructs. But that doesn't mean that all functions should be marked as `async`. `async` wraps a function into a promise, if the function executes synchronous code, this wrapping can cause an error (you expect the string for example, but function returns a resolved promise). Another example when the function executes async code, but doesn't use intermediate result, in this case it's enough just return the result of async call.

You should use `async/await` when:

- The function executes **sync** code, and you want to wrap the result into a promise (for creating a promise chain).
- The function executes **async** code and you need an intermediate result.
- The function executes **async** code and you *don't* need an intermediate result, but you want execute code in series (for processing each item in array for example).

Let's consider some examples:

1.sync function, validates `userId`. `validateParams` returns `true/false`, `validateParams2` throws an error if `userId` is undefined. `validateParams3` returns a promise, and can be used for creating a promise chain: `validateParams3().then(...)`.

```
let validateParams = (userId) => {
  return userId;
}

let validateParams2 = (userId) => {
  if (!userId) {
    throw new Error('userId is undefined');
  }
}

let validateParams3 = (userId) => {
  if (!userId) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('userId is undefined'));
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

2.async function, doesn't use intermediate result. `getUser` returns a pending promise (when `userId` is valid) or fulfilled promise (when `userId` is undefined). It should return a promise, because `getUser` can be used for starting a promise chain: `createUser().then(...)`. `getUser2` and `getUser3` do the same thing, return a promise. The promise is requred here to avoid getting `unhandledError` error, because `validateParams2` can throw an error. `getUser2` makred as `async` (to create a promise automatically), and `getUser3` returns a promise.

```
let getUser = (userId) => {
  if (validateParams(userId)) {
    return db.getUserById(userId);
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
}

let getUser2 = async (userId) => {
  validateParams2(userId);
  return db.getUserById(userId);
}

let getUser3 = (userId) => {
  return Promise
    .resolve(userId)
    .then(validateParams2)
    .then(() => db.getUserById(userId);
}
```

3.async function, uses an intermediate result:

```
let updateUser = async (userId, userData) => {
  let user = await getUser(userId);
  _.extend(user, userData);

  return db.saveUser(user);
}
```

The functions above can be used this way:

```
// with async
let fn = async (userId, userData) => { 
  try {
    let user = await updateUser(userId, userData);
    console.log(user);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

// without async
let fn2 = (userId, userData) => { 
  updateUser(userId, userData)
    .then(user => console.log(user))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, can you please explain or include more information/example on "_Use async function only when you want to do something with the result of async call inside this function._" As I will change the title for more general topic to help other users. I would really appreciate it as this is a learning process for me as well.

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf added explanation about using `async/await`.

Comment: I don't understand why you changed my example, and talking that it doesn't work? Why you added callback in `connection.query`? Also you added `records.map` in `bar`... So currently it's absolutely different question. My answer was for original question.

Comment: I see, ok I know what is the problem `connection.query` doesn't return a promise (I was thinking it returns...). You need to _promisify_ `connection.query` - create a promise. Updated the code.

Comment: God.. I am about to cry,, finally works! Thanks :D I will delete junk edits and comments (maybe include promisify info for others)

Comment: :), I glad that I helped you, `connection.query` confused me a little bit.