# Calling async function return Promise object with numbers for property names

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

I am calling this code:

```
Permissions.check('photo')
      .then(response => {
        ...
      });
```

Here I can use response object to check value.
But I want to call this with await like:

```
async function test() {
  let test = await Permissions.check('photo');
  return test;
}
...
let result = test();
```

But this returns me Promise object that look like this:

```
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
```

And value that I usually get in `response` here I get in `result._55`.
What can I do to get proper object?

Comment: It would work if you combine `await` and `then`. I think it is a bad practice though. Try `let test; await Permissions.check('photo').then((response) => test=response);`

Comment: I asked a similar question before and here is a VERY helpful information in the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765114/how-to-await-for-a-function-or-a-database-query-and-then-process-results-and-fi

Answer (score 1):

Here a few options you have:

1. Stick with whatever you were already doing.

   ```
   function main() {
     Permissions.check('photo')
       .then(response => {
         ...
       });
   }
   main();
   ```
2. If you want to do something like `let result = Permissions.check()` where `Permissions.check()` returns a promise, you actually need (a) use the `await` keyword and (b) put the `let result` statement inside an `async` function.

   ```
   async function main() {
     let result = await Permissions.check('photo');
   }
   main();
   ```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you expect to be able to use `test` in a synchronous way like this?

```
let result = test();
result._55; // ...
```

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but that won't work.

Async functions don't convert an asynchronous action to a synchronous action. Async functions return a promise which wraps the value in the `return ...` statement. This means that your `test` function is equivalent to:

```
function test() {
  return Permissions.check('photo').then(result => result);
}
```

... which is pointless, because you now have to use it like this:

```
test().then(response => {
  response._55; // ...
});
```

Just stick with your first solution.

Comment: Was this a comment or an answer?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf, no, the OP never said the first solution doesn't work. They just expected the async function `test` to be offer a nicer (a "synchronous") way of accessing the `result` object. I explained that `test` doesn't return this `result` object, but a promise wrapping this object.