# How do I get my code to run in a certain order?

Tags: javascript, mysql

So I'm trying to get my code to run a certain way. I have this query class and I am trying to make a new query object with a variable 'departments' that is supposed to hold the MySQL query results. For context, I have these two snippets of code in two separate files. However, when I run the server.js file (the first snippet of code), it goes through that file before going through the query.js file (the second snippet of code). I want it to run the server.js file until it gets to the line where I initialize and set the department variable, then I want it to run the query.js file.

```
getDepartmentsQuery = new Query();
const departments = getDepartmentsQuery.getDepartment(); // here i want js to run the other file with the class
addRole(departments);

const addRole = (departments) => {
  console.log(departments); // this logs 'undefined'
}
```

```
class Query {

    getDepartment() {
        db.query('SELECT name FROM department', (err,res) => {
            const departments = res;
            return departments;
        });
    }

};
```

What happens is that the departments variable in my server.js file is undefined when I want it to hold the results from the MySQL query I'm running in my query.js file. I've tried making the function async and using await but that didn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to await for a function or a database query? And then process results and finally send them back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765114/how-to-await-for-a-function-or-a-database-query-and-then-process-results-and-fi)

Comment: @kmoser I tried making my functions async and using await, but that didn't work either

Comment: Please show us the async/await code you tried.

Comment: @kmoser I tried doing const departments = await getDepartmentsQuery.getDepartment()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it:

```
getDepartmentsQuery = new Query();
const departments = await getDepartmentsQuery.getDepartment();
addRole(departments);

const addRole = (departments) => {
  console.log(departments);
}
```

```
class Query {

    async getDepartment() {
        let results = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.query('SELECT name FROM department', (err,res) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    resolve(res)
                }
            });
        });

        return results;
    }

};
```

Thanks @kmoser for the link!